# Laravel shared data from external resource fetched by HTTP in view composer

Tags: laravel, global-variables, laravel-blade

I would like to share global data for all blades which is fetched from an external API. For this reason I created a ViewServiceProvider which boots as it follows
`View::composer('*', CommonsComposer::class);`

than in composer I would like to fetch the data as it follows

```
public function __construct()
{
    try {
        $response = Http::get(env('WP_API_URL') . 'bdb/v1/options');
        $this->wpData = $response->json();
    } catch (HttpException $exception) {
        dump($exception);
    }
}
```

but here is not best place to do this because when a blade template is rendered then the call would be fired as well.

How to limit the HTTP call to one request?

Comment: Is this global data the same for all requests?

Comment: @SahandMoghadam yes

Comment: So why don't you store a flag in cache and check it on every request?

Comment: yes I could do that, but I'm looking for a better workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We think you can register composer class with singleton pattern. Something like this:

In **`ViewServiceProvider`** :

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton(\path_to_composer\CommonsComposer::class);
}
```

Comment: and how would this solve the multiple request issue?

Comment: With singleton, function ____construct() in CommonsComposer will be called only once time

Comment: You can read more about it with keyword `Singleton binding`. Hope it can help you